# What date was a table loaded into PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgadmin-3

Is it possible to find out the date a table was loaded into a PostGIS schema using PgAdmin3?

The tables are usually supplied from varying external sources.

Comment: You need a date column which is populated. http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-insert/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways:

1. By creating trigger functions for your data tables, which insert "update timestamps" into an update_log table. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/899473)
2. If you want to find out the historical update time for a table, the manual method is to find the file node name from the pg_class for your table

   ```
   select relfilenode from pg_class where relname = 'tablename'
   ```

   Locate the relfilenode file in your system. The last updated system time of that file node is your last update time of your table. (from [PostgreSQL forums](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/to-find-table-stats-for-last-update-time-tp2142054p4575271.html))